# How can I get the value from a cell which is in the same row as the button I am pressing

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

So I'm trying to get the value of the USUARIO column when I'm pressing the button of its same row:
[For example, if I was about to press the first button, it should give me 3 as a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2OU0.png)

In my code I have this:

```
function(response) {
                        var t = "";
                        var tr = "";
                        tr += "<thead>";
                        tr += "<th>USUARIO</th>";
                        tr += "<th>FECHA INICIO</th>";
                        tr += "<th>FECHA FIN</th>";
                        tr += "<th>TIPO EMERGENCIA</th>";
                        tr += "<th>LOCALIZACIÓN</th>";
                        tr += "<th>DESACTIVADOR</th>";
                        tr += "</thead>";
                        tr +=  '<tbody id="tbody' +  i +">';
                        tr += '<td class= "OIDCELL">' + response[i].usuario_oid + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + response[i].fechainicio + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + response[i].fechafin + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + response[i].tipoemergencia_tipo
                                + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + enlace + "</td>";
                        if (response[i].desactivador == 0){
                            tr += '<td> <button type="button" onclick="cambiarDesactivador()">Desactivar</button></td>';
                        }else{
                            tr += "<td>" + response[i].desactivador + "</td>";
                        }
                        
                        tr += "</tr>";
                        tr += "</tbody>";
                        }
                        t += tr;
                        document.getElementById("historicoUser").innerHTML += t;
                    }
```

So in which way am I able to get the value of the USUARIO column of the same row of the pressed button?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Could you add explanatory text to your code? Your code is uncommented, so you are not making it easy for answerers to understand what you have done, what you explicitly do understand, and what you do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly pass in the value `response[i].usuario_oid` which you are showing in the column to your button's onClick function

example: `cambiarDesactivador(response[i].usuario_oid)`

Answer (score 1):

Some comments on the code, which has many errors:

1. `function(response) {...}` is not a valid function declaration or expression
2. The *t* variable seems redundant
3. Don't mix the semantics of double and single quotes. Use single quotes for javascript, double for HTML (see below)
4. All that `+=` is inefficient, just create a single string and assign it to *tr* like:

```
tr = '<thead>' +
     '<th>USUARIO</th>' +
     '<th>FECHA INICIO</th>' +
     ...
     '<tbody id="tbody' +  i + '">' +
     ...
```

To get the row of the button that is clicked, get a reference to the button then use [*closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the tr ancestor. [Table rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) have a *cells* collection, the first cell is index 0, etc.

So pass *this* from the listener, go up to the row then get the content of the first cell, e.g.

```js
function getFirstCellContent(el) {
  let row = el.closest('tr');
  console.log(row.cells[0].textContent);
}
```

```css
table {
 border-left: 1px solid #999999;
 border-top: 1px solid #999999;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
 border-right: 1px solid #999999;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>One<td><button onclick="getFirstCellContent(this)">Click me</button>
  <tr><td>Two<td><button onclick="getFirstCellContent(this)">Click me</button>
  <tr><td>Three<td><button onclick="getFirstCellContent(this)">Click me</button>
</table>
```